# How to change cpu affinity on linux with python in realtime?

Tags: python, linux, affinity

I know I can use `os.sched_setaffinity` to set affinity, but it seems that I can't use it to change affinity in realtime. Below is my code:

First, I have a cpp program

```cpp
// test.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

void workload() {
    unsigned long long int sum = 0;
    for (long long int i = 0; i < 50000000000; ++i) {
        sum += i;
    }
    std::cout << "Sum: " << sum << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    unsigned int num_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    std::cout << "Creating " << num_threads << " threads." << std::endl;

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(workload));
    }

    for (auto& thread : threads) {
        thread.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Then, I compile it

```
g++ test.cpp -O0
```

and I'll get an `a.out` file in the same directory.

Then, still in the same directory, I have a python file

```py
# test.py
from subprocess import Popen
import os
import time
a = set(range(8, 16))
b = set(range(4, 12))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    proc = Popen("./a.out", shell=True)
    pid = proc.pid
    print("pid", pid)
    tic = time.time()
    while True:
        if time.time() - tic < 10:
            os.sched_setaffinity(pid, a)
            print("a", os.sched_getaffinity(pid))
        else:
            os.sched_setaffinity(pid, b)
            print("b", os.sched_getaffinity(pid))
        res = proc.poll()
        if res is None:
            time.sleep(1)
        else:
            break
```

`a.out` would run a long time, and my expect for `test.py` is: in the first 10 seconds, I would see cpu 8~15 busy while 0~7 idle; and after 10 seconds, I would see cpu 4~11 busy while others idle. But as I observed with `htop`, I found that in the first 10 seconds, my observation indeed met my expect, however after 10 seconds, I could see `b {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}` every second, as if I successfully set the affinity; but on `htop`, I still found that cpu 8~15 busy while 0~7 idle until the program normally stopped, which means I faild to set the affinity.

I'd like to ask why would this happen? I read the [manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html) but didn't find anything to mention about it. And it seems that python's `os.sched_setaffinity` doesn't return anything so I can't see the result.

I'm using AMD cpu, but I don't think that matters.

Comment: What does `taskset -a -p <pid>` show?

Comment: @KlausD. In first 10 sec, it is `ff00`, and after 10 sec it is `ff0`, which seems to be right. I used `strace` to `run taskset -a -p <pid>`, and found `sched_getaffinity` in it, so I guess maybe it uses `sched_getaffinity` too, just like python's `os.sched_getaffinity`. But I saw I failed to set affinity after 10 sec by `htop`. Would `sched_getaffinity` be wrong or `htop` be wrong?

Comment: Affinity is a per-thread concept, so maybe you need to set the affinity for each of the target process threads.

Comment: @nneonneo If you're right, then the first time `os.sched_getaffinity` should not work either, but it works. I think the answer by @Krishna Gunjan about cpu cache is somehow reasonable, but his suggestion doesn't work for me.

Comment: far-out guess - it might be a race in which your `setaffinity` call fires before the threads are created?

Comment: @nneonneo I tried it and you're right, if I comment `os.sched_setaffinity` in the first 10 sec, affinity set of "b" also don't work. So I need to find out how to get all the threads' id of the process and set them. You can write your answer and I can accept your answer.

Comment: @nneonneo Sorry that there's another correct answer so I need to accept that. Still very thankful for your reply, because I succeeded after read your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the problem is that on Linux, sched_setaffinity() affects a thread, not a process. The main thread has the same id as the process, but subsequent threads have different ids, and they inherit the CPU affinity from the parent thread.

Apparently Python is quick enough to set the CPU affinity of the main thread, so the child threads inherited the initial CPU mask from the main thread, but changing the CPU affinity of the main thread later won't affect already running threads (but it would, in theory, affect new threads if they are spawned from the main thread later).

To work around it, you can introduce a helper function like this:

```
def ChangeProcessAffinity(pid, cpus):
  for tid in map(int, os.listdir(f'/proc/{pid}/task/')):
    try:
      os.sched_setaffinity(tid, cpus)
    except e:
      pass  # maybe log the error instead
```

...then call that in your while loop. Note that there are two problems with this:

1. The solution using procfs is specific to Linux,
2. The solution is inherently racy: it's possible that threads start or stop after listing them, which is also why you need an exception handler.

I don't think there is an atomic way to set the CPU affinity for all threads in a process; the `taskset` command line utility (which you already found) does approximately the same as I suggested above.

If you want a more robust solution, I think it's best to implement it inside the C++ binary itself (if you have control over it), since it knows when threads are started or stopped.

Comment: You're right. I had thought that `os.sched_setaffinity` could only accept pid due to the [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sched_setaffinity), but in fact it could also accept tid.

Comment: I use `psutil` to find all threads of one process, which I think is easier to understand in code.